# How do I look at my mosquitto.conf file in terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, mqtt, mosquitto

I have installed mosquitto on my MacBook Pro running MacOS 12.7.4 Monterey using Brew.
I was able to mosquitto_sub in one Terminal window and mosquitto_pub in another one and it worked.  I could see the pub in the sub window.
I then put

```
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
```

and when I tried to _pub from another window I got.

```
New connection from :: 1:49XXX on port 1883
New client connected from ::1:XXXX as auto-XXXXetc  (p2,c1, k60).
Client auto-XXXXetc disconnected.
```

I also put

```
listener 1884
```

I would like to look at my mosquitto.conf file but I am not sure how do that.
I have tried to connect to this broker using the app MQTTAnylizer but I get

```
Connection refused (NW:61)
```

I have address at 192.168.68.XXX and port at 1883.

Can someone show me exactly what to put into Terminal to see my mosquitto.conf file
and
explain why my connection is being refused.

I am on the same wifi using TPlink deco system.

I am rather frustrated and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: How are you editing a file you can not read?

Comment: `nano` is one option [on the mac](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/guide/terminal/apdb02f1133-25af-4c65-8976-159609f99817/2.12/mac/11.0) (i.e. `nano $(brew --prefix)/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`). However you could just use your normal text editor. Typing things like `listener 1883` into the command prompt will not help (and is not a good idea because you might end up running something unexpected). The most likely reason it's not working from another machine is because, by default, Mosquitto only accepts local connections (I think you realise this based on your comments).